# facebook sdk Asp.net and using "Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for .NET and ASP.NET"

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to create my first facebook sdk Asp.net and using "Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for .NET and ASP.NET" as a guide located here:

- http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started/

The problem I am having is that after the FB.init() and FB.Event.subscribe() I don't think the function in the event ever gets called, so there is no post back to my Webform1.aspx so I can get the accessToken.

I did read this post but they had a different problem with breaking out of the login loop:

- [Login with Facebook C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230134/login-with-facebook-c-sharp)

Here are the events that are happening when I execute the WebForm1.aspx:

1. I put breakpoints at various places
2. I hit F5 in VS 2012 to Run
3. It loads WebForm1.aspx
4. void Page_Load is correctly called
5. FB.init() is called
6. FB.Event.subscribe() is called
7. The facebook login image is displayed on WebForm1.aspx
8. I click on the facebook login image
9. https://www.facebook.com/login.php is displayed.
10. I provide the credentials I used to obtain the AppID
11. I click Login button in the lower right corner
12. I get a dialog that states "The page you are viewing is trying to
     close the window. Do you want to close this window?"
13. I choose Yes
14. It brings me back to WebForm1.aspx
15. void Page_Load is not called, as there is no postback
16. There is no posted value in accessToken.

    ```
    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '6453703688*****', // App ID
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        alert("about to subscribe to event");
        // Additional initialization code here
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
            alert(response.status);
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                // TODO: Handle the access token
                // Do a post to the server to finish the logon
                // This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
                var form = document.createElement("form");
                form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
                //form.setAttribute("action", '/FacebookLogin.ashx');
                form.setAttribute("action", 'WebForm1.aspx');

                var field = document.createElement("input");
                field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                field.setAttribute("name", 'accessToken');
                field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
                form.appendChild(field);

                document.body.appendChild(form);
                form.submit();

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app
                alert("has not authenticated your app");
            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                alert("user isn't logged in to Facebook.");
            }
        });
    };


    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
    ```

Comment: Well, I figured out it works in FireFox, but not IE. So I need to determine which settings I need to change in IE to get it to work.